# r raster clusterR error when running overlay

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-raster

I am trying to write a function to run several concurrent cell-wise calculations on a raster. My hope is to use the raster package's built-in parallel processing code to speed up processing.

I am getting an error: "Error in get(name, envir = envir) : object 'mn' not found". This error occurs at the ##### ERROR HERE ##### marker below, where the function is attempting to run raster::overlay.

I see that this error is from the get function, and indicates that the mn object is not accessible to all clusters.

How can I write this code so that objects will be in the appropriate environments? Thanks.

Here is a basic version of my code:

```
my_func <- function(file = NULL, na.rm = TRUE, ncores = 2){
    # begin parallel processing
    raster::beginCluster(ncores, type='SOCK')

    # load data from file as raster brick
    data <- raster::brick(file)

    # calculate the standard deviation of the brick
    sd <- raster::clusterR(x = data, fun = function(data){ raster::calc(x = data, fun = sd, na.rm = na.rm) })

    # calculate mean - for layer i, mean is the mean of all layers but i
    set <- 1:raster::nbands(data) # marker to pass to for loop
    mn <- data # creates raster object to be filled with results
    for(i in set){
      subset <- set[-i]
      wrk <- raster::stack(x = data, bands = subset) # make stack of all but i
      mn_i <- raster::clusterR(x = wrk, fun = function(wrk){ raster::calc(x = wrk, fun = mean, na.rm = na.rm) }) # calculate mean of stack
      mn[[i]] <- mn_i # set values of appropriate band with results
    }

    # calculate z score
    ##### ERROR HERE #####
    z <- raster::clusterR(x = data, fun = function(data, mn){ raster::overlay(x = data, y = mn, fun = function(data, mn){ data - mn }, na.rm = na.rm }, export = mn)

    # normalize z score
    ##### I assume the error would also occur here #####
    z <- raster::clusterR(x = data, fun = function(z, sd){ raster::overlay(x = z, y = sd, fun = function(z, sd){ z / sd }, na.rm = na.rm) }, export = sd)

    # end parallel processing
    raster::endCluster()


    # return result
    return(result)

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with multi-band rasters the clusterR function can be rolled into a for loop.

```
    # example data
    data("Rlogo")
    data <- raster::brick(Rlogo)

    # calculate sd
    sd <- raster::calc(data, sd)

    # calculate mean (mean of layer x is mean of all layers but x)
    mn <- data
    set <- 1:nlayers(data)
    for (i in set) {
      subset <- set[-i]
      wrk <- raster::stack(x = data, bands = subset)
      mn_i <- raster::calc(x = wrk, fun = mean)
      mn[[i]] <- mn_i
    }

    # calculate z score
    z <- data
    set <- 1:nlayers(data)
    fun1 <- function(x,y){x-y}
    raster::beginCluster()
    for (i in set){
      wrk <- raster::stack(data[[i]], mn[[i]])
      z_i <- clusterR(x = wrk, fun = raster::overlay, arg = list(fun = fun1))
      z[[i]] <- z_i
      rm(z_i, wrk)
    }

    # normalize z score
    fun2 <- function(x,y){x/y}
    for(i in set){
      wrk <- raster::stack(z[[i]], sd)
      z_i <- clusterR(x = wrk, fun = raster::overlay, arg = list(fun = fun2))
      z[[i]] <- z_i
      rm(z_i, wrk)
    }
    raster::endCluster()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `x` and `y` in `overlay()` but using `data`, `mn`, `z` and `sd` as parameter. Use:

```
z <- raster::clusterR(x = data, fun = function(data, mn){ raster::overlay(x = data, y = mn, fun = function(x, y){ x - y }, na.rm = na.rm }, export = mn)

z <- raster::clusterR(x = data, fun = function(z, sd){ raster::overlay(x = z, y = sd, fun = function(x, y){ x / y }, na.rm = na.rm) }, export = sd)
```

---

**Propose**: (always provide example data)

```
library(raster)

set.seed(123)

r <- raster()
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)

data <- r
mn <- setValues(r , rnorm(ncell(r)))
data[1:1000] <- NA # to force some NA testing

sd <- r*2

fun1 <- function(x,y){x - y}
fun2 <- function(x,y){x / y}

beginCluster()
z <- clusterR(stack(data,mn), overlay, arg = list(fun = fun1))
z <- clusterR(stack(z,sd), overlay, arg = list(fun = fun2))
endCluster()

plot(z)
```

[image]

Comment: This still results in the same error. I notice that you did not use quotes for `export =`. I tried running the code without quoting the argument to export and got a new error: _invalid for loop sequence_. Does this code require quotes for export arguments? The help for clusterR implies that quotes are required.

Comment: Sorry for missing example data. Your code works with some modifications to work for multiple bands. Please see my answer.